# Apache redircting when it shouldnt

Tags: apache, redirects, linux

I have inherited a LAMP server with a lot of customization.

I want to enable mod_status in apache to get some monitoring of apache started. Problem is, with mod_status enabled in the httpd.conf, I am not allowed to travel to the http://"serverIP"/server-status URL because apache is redirecting me to a 'landing page'.

If I type any invalid URL for the server, it redirects to this page, all error document pages have been hashed out from the httpd.conf.

Any assistance to where this has may have been configured or if there is a way to override it so I can get to the url http://"serverIP"/server-status ?

Answer (score 1):

If there are Rewrite rules in your .htaccess that cause this, then you should be able to add a condition to ignore this particular URL. See [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for some more info (look for RewriteCond).